# Assembly OS tutorial: Why is the push command pushing 'A' down by 2?

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, i386

I am following a os dev tutorial and learning the basics of assembly programming.
https://github.com/cfenollosa/os-tutorial/blob/master/04-bootsector-stack/boot_sect_stack.asm

Atm I am trying to understand how the stack works, my assumptions:

- It grows down from high memory to low memory i.e. 0xFFFFFF --> 0x000000

Here is my code.

```
mov bp, 0x8000 ; this is an address far away from 0x7c00 so that we don't get overwritten
mov sp, bp ; if the stack is empty then sp points to bp

push 'A'
push 'B'
push 'C'

; to show how the stack grows downwards
mov al, [0x7ffe] ; 0x8000 - 2 ; why is this minus 2 if it's directly below
int 0x10
```

And heres my stack diagram:
[image]

The output is:

```
A
```

My question is why is the address of A 0x7ffe when it is directly below 0x8000 (minus 2), surely this is 1 below?

Comment: In 16 bit mode each `push` is 2 bytes. Consult the instruction set reference. Also, x86 is little endian, so the `A` is going to be in the byte with the lower address.

Comment: On a side note: the stack pointer is made up of the pair SS:SP . In the diagram it appears the OP has assumed SS is zero. That may not actually be the case. If setting SP you should be setting SS as well.

Comment: On the other hand, the code assumes a different thing, namely that `SS==DS` which again may or may not be the case. Also just noticed this: _sp points to bp_. Of course `sp` does not point to `bp`, nothing does, since registers don't have addresses on x86. _sp_ just has the same value as _bp_ initially, so they both point to the same place (but not to each other).

Comment: Why only dry paper run? If you would inspect stack memory in debugger, you would see by yourself two bytes were pushed and `sp` did decrement by 2. It's much easier to watch these things in debugger, when you are not sure how something works and the description is not clear enough.